# Listlayers, but exclude group names/feature dataset names with Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, versioning

I am looking for a way to loop through all the feature classes (feature layers) within a mxd, to then use some geoprocessing tools on them. Before I run these geoproccesses, the script needs to change these feature classes to a certain workversion.

I have the script working the way I want except for groups or feature datasets. With the looping it thinks that these group names or feature dataset names are a layer of their own and therefore tries to change to a workversion, needless to say the script errors and I am left with no data being changed.

For grouped feature classes this is rather easy, remove the group. However this doesn't work for feature datasets.

My question is:
Is there a way to "ungroup" feature datasets or better yet, skip the names of groups/feature datasets all together in the script?

My script as it is now:

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping

Project_number = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
inWorkspace = "G:/ZN_KGD@pkgd.sde"
parentVersion = "ZN_KGD_DIENSTVERSIE"

# Execute CreateVersion
arcpy.CreateVersion_management(inWorkspace, parentVersion, "ExPimp_{}".format(Project_number), "PUBLIC")

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("G:\\zn\\NM\\GGB\\Applicaties-Admin\\Kerngis\\ExpImp\\{}\\{}.mxd".format(Project_number, Project_number))  # Uses your currently open MXD
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, ''): # Loop through dataframes
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df): # Loop through layers


         arcpy.ChangeVersion_management (lyr.name,
                                            "TRANSACTIONAL",
                                        "ZN_KGD.Export_{}".format(Project_number))
```

I am working with ArcMap 10.3.1
I have tried the solution given below on all the possible ways I can imagen, with no luck. As my knowledge of python/arcpy is very limited at best, would it be possible to explain the thought process behind it?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [isGroupLayer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) property to identify group layers to ignore them.  To ignore feature dataset layers you could use the [dataSource](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) property to evaluate the layer path and ignore those that have an extra level deep being the feature dataset layers inside the database.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("G:\\zn\\NM\\GGB\\Applicaties-Admin\\Kerngis\\ExpImp\\{}\\{}.mxd".format(Project_number, Project_number))  # Uses your currently open MXD
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, ''): # Loop through dataframes
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df): # Loop through layers
        if not lyr.isGroupLayer:
            fcString = lyr.dataSource.split('.gdb\\')[1]
            fcOnly = fcString.find('\\')
            if fcOnly == -1:
                arcpy.ChangeVersion_management (lyr.name,
                                            "TRANSACTIONAL",
                                        "ZN_KGD.Export_{}".format(Project_number))
```

Comment: I am still rather new to python/Arcpy, would this ignore the entire group/feature dataset or would it just ignore the group name but still take the feature classes within the group? The main thing that I am trying to "ignore" is the feature dataset name called "KGD_ZN.Topologie" while still looping throuhg the feature layers within it. As the code is now it comes back with errors. I have tried replacing the ('.gdb\\') with ('KGD_ZN.Topologie\\'), but I am not sure if that is correct.

Comment: The solution suggested by artwork21 only ignores the actual group layer, but applies the rest of the code to all non-group layers, no matter if they are inside a group layer or not.